# How to define a common type in Java without defining a superclass or an interface?

Tags: java

I have a method that takes in Object as its argument.

```
public String toStr(Object o) {}
```

There are two factory methods that generate two different instances.

```
A a = FactoryA.generate() 
B b = FactoryB.generate()
```

In my code,

```
Object y;
If (x) {
    y = FactoryA.generate() 
} else {
    y = FactoryB.generate()
}
toStr(y)
```

Is there a way to define a common type for A and B so that I can pass that common type to toStr() instead of using Object because I want a more specific type instead of Object for type checking. If class A and B had methods or fields in common, I would have made a superclass C or an interface C, so that I can replace Object with C. But A and B don't have common methods or fields. What's the best way to define a common type for A and B for this case? Are empty interfaces or empty abstract classes best way to go?

Comment: Just make a marker interface with no methods.

Comment: Is there only 2 possible different variations of classes (A & B in your example)?

Using method overloading could be an alternative that could cater for limited number of variations.

Comment: It's unclear why you would want to do this. If the classes have no common methods, how can you have any sensible implementation of `toStr` that handles both? (Of course, they both extend `Object`, so you must be using only methods defined on `Object` - And then what's wrong with your current implementation?)

Comment: a. The interface doe's not have to be empty. Why not have `public String toStr() {}` in that interface ? b. For type checking you can add explicit test (`instanceof`)  c. Also consider generics

Comment: I'd use generics for this, but keep `y` as an `Object`.

Comment: @Brick To be more specific, I am using toJson() method Gson, so yes it's probably using methods defined on Object.

Comment: Could you elaborate how I would use generics in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to define a common type in Java without defining a superclass or
>   an interface?

In Java, the two mechanisms for defining types are interfaces and classes (esp. abstract classes).  Because Java will only allow a class to extend one other class, using an abstract class for this purpose won't work well.  Classes may implement any number of interfaces, however, and an empty interface still defines a type.  Without knowing more about your use case, it isn't possible to say even whether you really need to define a type.

*If your intention is for your code to signal to some kind of external framework that some special kind of processing should occur*, then the two mechanisms the language has to offer are:

- marker interfaces
- annotations

There are plusses and minuses to each of these two approaches.  The advantage of marker interfaces is that they actually do define a type and an API can be written to restrict arguments to this type.  Annotations allow for the specification of metadata or configuration information at the site of use.  The Java EE framework makes extensive use of annotations in client code.  These annotations in Java EE can and usually do provide customized configuration metadata.

There is a concise treatment on the merits of marker interfaces versus annotations in Effective Java, 2nd Ed by Joshua Bloch.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an interface as follows:

```
interface I {

     default String toStr() {   
        //implement 
    }

     //OR : String toStr();
}

class A implements I{} 
class B implements I{}
```

use it :

```
I i;
if (x) {
  i = FactoryA.generate(); //construct A
} else {
  i = FactoryB.generate(); //construct B
}
i.toStr();
```

Comment: Strictly speaking this doesn't answer the question, which is how to accomplish this without superclasses or interfaces.

Comment: Yes, under this assumption: "If class A and B had methods or fields in common, I would have made a superclass C or an interface", which I question. I think `toStr()` can be the common method.